Trying to find African American lit story
Help! I remember reading a short story (maybe novel) in African American lit class in way back in college that had a side character, a cool, feminist, commie aunt who was crashing on their couch who "could never work for any man." It was written or set in the 70s or 80s. I can't for the life of me remember anything else about the story, sorry.
